# How grub tells kernel where to find initramfs?

Tags: grub2, grub, initramfs

In grub there is the following line which loads the initramfs file into memory:

```
initrd16 /<initramfs_file>.img
```

But how actually does kernel knows that its init is in that image ?

Is it some kernel configuration ? which ?

I try to understand how grub/kernel knows how to boot into the above initramfs.

There is no much information on this topic, so any comment is appreciated.